# How do I make a form's values change a page's CSS in real-time (without having to refresh the page)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, button

I am attempting to change the CSS on the page as a user types values into a form using javascript. For example - if they type a color value into said field it turns said button to that color. Or changes size if they provide input in the size field. I have not been able to find any examples relating to this. If you could point me to any resources regarding this that would be awesome!

**This is my first post, please let me know if I am doing anything incorrectly.

Comment: You need to post the code you've tried.  Finding resources for people is considered off-topic for SO.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var b = button.offsetWidth;
function a(input) {
button.style.width = b + input.value + "px";
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="number" onchange="a(this);" min="5">
<button id="button">Hello World</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

this input receives code of colors. ff0 - for example

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
function changeColor(input) {
  btn.style.background="#"+input.value;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input id="inp" type="text" onInput="changeColor(this);">
    <button id="btn">Click</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough this is something I decided to do a few weeks ago, you just create a blank style in the head section of your html page, add an id and use jquery to set the content of the style upon keyup of what ever you decide to use to set the values, e.g.

```
<pre contenteditable></pre>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('pre').keyup(function(){
        $('#yourstyletagid').html($(this).html());
    });
});
</script>
```